# how to preserve newline '\n' while using Jinja2 striptags filter?

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, strip-tags

A Pure Text Form for user's post, I want to strip all HTML tags in the post content, but preserve newline `\n` to divide paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not with the `striptags` filter as it unconditionally replaces all whitespace sequences with a single space.

A work-around would be to replace newlines with a unique placeholder first, then strip tags, and then replace the placeholder with newlines. This is somewhat risky in that the input text could contain the placeholder:

```
text | replace('\n', '-*- newline -*-') | striptags | replace('-*- newline -*-', '\n')
```

The `striptags` implementation is otherwise a straightforward regex replacement:

```
import re

_striptags_re = re.compile(r'(<!--.*?-->|<[^>]*>)')
replaced = _striptags_re.sub('', input_text)
```

(with the whitespace handling step omitted)

You could do this in your Python code before passing the value to the template, or replicate this in a custom filter.

Comment: got it, thanks for your detailed explanation! it seems Python - bleach would be considerable for this question?

Comment: @rogwan: the escaping is part of the [`MarkupSafe` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MarkupSafe), which already takes care of HTML safety otherwise. Bleach gives you a 'safe subset' of HTML, with a whitelist of allowed mark-up; this is different from stripping *all* HTML markup; it's a different usecase. If that's what you want to support, then just use Bleach and Jinja2 together (pass usertext through Bleach, then mark that as safe in Jinja2 when interpolating).

Comment: OK understand, I will try this suggestion, thank you Martijn.